# How can I debug an AJAX error in VBO? (PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'uri'

Tags: views, debugging

I have a view that lists all the user accounts on my site.  With VBO, I have a rules component, **Resave user account** (action set, action: save entity (user), no *force saving immediately*).

Recently, when I attempt to re-save all user accounts, I got an error on **id=4037**:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /en/batch?id=**4037**&op=do StatusText: Service
>   unavailable (with message) ResponseText: PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (filesize, status,
>   timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   1375690632 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7153 of
>   /Volumes/Bullfrog/om/includes/common.inc).

And when I attempted to save all accounts again, the error occurred on **id=4039**:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /en/batch?id=**4039**&op=do StatusText: Service
>   unavailable (with message) ResponseText: PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (filesize, status,
>   timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   1375691655 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7153 of
>   /Volumes/Bullfrog/om/includes/common.inc).

So, if I simply continue to re-save again and again, eventually all the accounts will get re-saved, but to execute this bulk operation takes about 20 minutes each time, so I will waste several hours this way.  How can I analyze what is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bizarre [core bug](https://drupal.org/node/1443158) in which image files stored in user profile fields behave oddly that was getting triggered by Rules under some weird conditions.

Answer (score 2):

`Duplicate entry '' for key 'uri'` actually says a little more than AlexK realizes, it says both that there's a file without a uri, hence the `''`, and that you have more than one of these, hence the `Duplicate entry`.

I'm guessing there's a filefield on your users, and some of these have lost part of their data for reasons I don't understand. (The same thing happened to me once during a faulty export-from-one-site-and-import-to-another).

Why the process can be "forced" by repetition I don't understand, but close inspection of the user entity and any fields that could have a 'uri' key, both through devel and the raw data in the DB, should reveal what the source of the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The database error you are getting there is due to Drupal trying to insert a managed file into the database which already exists. The error **Duplicate entry '' for key 'uri'** tells us that Drupal is trying to create a file using a URI which already exists in the database.

IMO what I think is happening is that the VBO is re-saving each user account correctly, but is trying to create a new file instance for attached files, instead of updating each attached file correctly.

I'm not sure how you would fix this specifically, but it seems to me this is a problem with the way VBO handles resaving user account. Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this information.  I should note that it is not all accounts though; it saves about 800 accounts without a problem, and then suddenly runs into maybe 5 accounts that break the bulk operation, and then saves 300 more, and then runs into another group of accounts that break the operation.

Comment: yeah unfortunately I'm not well versed in the inner workings of VBO so I can't really help narrow down the problem in that regard. Maybe having a look at the structure of the "file_managed" table within the DB can give you a better understanding of whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Re-load the user using user_load() before passing it to user_save(), this will ensure that fields are correctly populated, and prevent this kind of error (here uri attributes are empty) from happening